# How do I evaluate this integral? $\int_0^1x^{-x}e^x\ln(x)dx=1-e$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

How do I evaluate this integral?

$$\int_0^1x^{-x}e^x\ln(x)dx=1-e$$

---

We apply integration by parts, but it seem too long and complicated. There must be an easy method for this type of integral. Can anybody give me a hint?

Comment: Hint: $x^{-x} e^{x} = e^{x(1-\ln x)}$. The derivative of $x(\ln x - 1)$ is exactly $\ln x$...

Comment: Ok, let work on it for a bit (+1)

Comment: I am teaching at the moment, busy

Comment: @adambui: so you know the answer in advance, but you still ask for it. What is your purpose, if I may dare to ask?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\int_0^1x^{-x}e^x\ln(x)dx= \int_0^1e^{x(1-\ln(x))}[-\ln(x)]dx=(-e)-(-e^0)=1-e.$$

Comment: For the confused reader: the derivative of $x(1-\ln x)$ is $-\ln x$. The minus sign that you have placed outside the second integral should not be there.

Comment: It remained the same after your edit (but should be correct now). Do not forget to accept the answer :)

Comment: I am a bit confused I am new to this site, accept what and edit what?